# c++ error c2015: too many characters in constant

Tags: c++

Sorry if it's something simple, but I'm new to C++ and haven't really gotten a good hold on it, yet. I need to build a calculator whose only named variables are pointers, and this is what I have so far, but I keep getting errors and I can't figure out why. Every error that always related to my if construct, though.

```
int main()
{
    //Creating variables

    //Values to perform operations on
    float *aptr = new(nothrow)float;
    float *bptr = new(nothrow)float;
    float *ansptr = new(nothrow)float;
    int *endptr = new(nothrow)int;
    char *operationptr = new(nothrow)char;

    cout << "Simple Operation Calculator" << endl; //Displays program name
    cout  << "Performs +, -, *, or / on any two real operands." << endl; //Describes nature of program to user

    *endptr = 1;
    while(*endptr = 1) //Creates a loop so that the user may perform as many operations as desired
    {
        //Prompts the user for the first operand
        cout << "First operand: " << endl;
        cin >> *aptr;

        //Prompts user for operator
        cout << "Operator(+,-,*,/): " << endl;
        cin >> *operationptr;

        //Prompts user for second operand
        cout << "Second operand: " << endl;
        cin >> *bptr;

        //Performs requested operation
        if(*operationptr == '+' || *operationptr == 'plus')
        {
            *ansptr = *aptr + *bptr;
        }
        else if(*operationptr == '-' || *operationptr == 'minus')
        {
            *ansptr = *aptr - *bptr;
        }
        else if(*operationptr == '*' || *operationptr ==  'times')
        {
            *ansptr = *aptr * *bptr;
        }
        else if(*operationptr == '/' || *operationptr == 'divided by')
        {
            if(*bptr = 0)
            {
                cout << "Cannot divide by zero. Terminating program." << endl;
                *endptr = 2;
                break;
            }
            *ansptr = *aptr / *bptr;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Invalid operand input. Terminating program." << endl;
            *endptr = 2;
            break;
        }

        //Displays results
        cout << *aptr << *operationptr << *bptr << " = " << *ansptr << endl;

        //Asks user if they wish to perform another operation. If so, they stay in loop. If not, then break from loop.
        cout << "Do you wish to perform another operation? (1 = yes, 2 = no)" << endl;
        cin >> *endptr;

        //If 1, loop repeats. If 2, program ends.
        if (*endptr == 2)
        {
            cout << "Thank you for using my program. Goodbye!" << endl;
        }
    } //end while loop

    return 0;

 }//end main function
```

Comment: For starters this is wrong: `while(*endptr = 1)` you want `while(*endptr == 1)`

Comment: Correct; and even `operationptr == "plus"` would be wrong semantically because the contents of the strings matters, not the pointer value. Once the restriction to use only pointers has been lifted use std::string. Or actually, use them right away with pointers to them, what the heck. The teacher asked for it.

Comment: If you are still getting used to using `==` instead of `=`, think about reversing the operands. `while(*endptr = 1)` will do something you probably don't want, but `while(1 = *endptr)` will fail to compile. (Some compilers will warn you about this kind of thing anyway).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are character literals (with `'`) and string literals (with `"`). Character literals have one character. String literals are arrays of characters. You can't write something like `'plus'` because it has more than one character (well technically you can, but it's a multi-character literal, but lets not go there).

Nonetheless, this wouldn't make any sense because `operationptr` points at a single `char` object. A single `char` can't contain the entire word `plus`.

If you want to be able to accept `plus` as input, then I suggest you start using strings. In fact, use `std::string`.

As a side note, you are using pointers and dynamic allocation far too often. You are also forgetting to `delete` the objects that you create with `new` - this is a memory leak. I imagine you have come from a language that uses `new` for all object creation. In C++, this is not necessary (and is not a good practice). Instead, you can declare objects like so:

```
float aptr;
```

There is no need to dereference this object. You can just use `aptr` directly as a `float`.

Comment: Thanks, that information is tremendously useful. I forgot about deleting the objects. Using new to allocate memory was a requirement of the assignment, as the only named variables allowed were pointers.

Comment: @HingleMcCringleberry That sounds like a terrible assignment! Show your teacher my article about [why raw pointers are rarely appropriate](http://josephmansfield.uk/articles/avoiding-ambiguity-raw-pointers.html)!

Answer (score 5):

`'plus'`

is a character constant, and can't contain more than one character.

`'+'` is fine, since it's a single character in a constant.

As per the comment on this answer,

`'plus'` could be ok, if the compiler is not expecting a `char`.

Comment: `'plus'` is legal C++, it just isn't a `char`, see [Why does this code with '1234' compile in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19394141/why-does-this-code-with-1234-compile-in-c)

Comment: The recommendation is to use `"` for multiple characters and `'` for single characters.