# Why putchar('\\\'); won't work

Tags: c++

I want to get the output `\\` ,so I type this to my code    `putchar('\\\');`
but it doesn't work out ,and I get the following error

> D:\c++ work\change\change.cpp(17) : error C2001: newline in constant
>   D:\c++ work\change\change.cpp(17) : fatal error C1057: unexpected end of file in macro expansion

why?

Comment: ugh. kindly format your code.

Comment: Are you asking about 2 escape-sequences and an unterminated multi-character-constant, or a single escape-sequence in a normal character-constant?

Comment: you have to escape both backslashes. `\\\\\`

Answer (score 5):

`\\` is an escaped \, then you have `\'` which is an escaped '. I'm guessing you meant to write: `putchar('\\');` or `putchar('\\\\');` (the latter being incorrect, you should do the former twice or use another function)

As you have it now (`\\\`) you're escaping the last ' which is causing your compiler to "misinterpret" your code. (I put misinterpret in quotes because it's actually interpreting it correctly, it's just not immediately obvious).

tl;dr

```
putchar('\\');
putchar('\\');
```

or

```
puts("\\\\");
```

will get you the correct output. ([See live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/89d6cc598a58ffc8))

Comment: @Deduplicator yes i should clear that up

Comment: @Deduplicator `'\\\\'` is actually [implementation-defined](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19394188/1009479).

Comment: @YuHao: You mean the value of `\\\\`. Yes. But it won't be the same as for a character constant... (In theory it could, yes again)

Comment: @Deduplicator My point is, it's not undefined behavior, just implementation-defined.