# What is the variable type of syntax: 'somestring' in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa

I saw this in Apple's framework files

```
enum
{
    kAudioFormatLinearPCM               = 'lpcm',
    kAudioFormatAC3                     = 'ac-3'
}
```

What is the type of `'lpcm'`and `'ac-3'`?
With a single character in the single quote like this `'a'`, I know it is a char; With double quotes like this `"text"`, I know it is a string.

But this? This makes me confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well first your in a type enum so it can only represent a int. I think apple using it to create unique vals for the enum but also wants it human readable.

For a much better explanation see: [What is the type of an enum whose values appear to be strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548289/what-is-the-type-of-an-enum-whose-values-appear-to-be-strings)

Comment: "Second single quotes represent a single byte" No, they don't.

Comment: Thanks, especially for the link:D

Answer (score 3):

Contrary to popular belief the type of `'c'` in C is `int`, not `char`. When you do something like `char c = 'c';`, there will be an implicit conversion from `int` to `char`, same as if you had written `char c = 99;`.

So to answer your question: the type of `'abcd'` is `int`, same as the type of `'c'`.

Comment: Thanks, seems like it is called integer character constant.Programmming books rarely mention this, it is odd.